Is a USB MUX needed in a USB-C 3.0 hub?
I would like to request some help if possible with a USB 3.0 hub utilizing a USB-C port to connect to the host.
The USB hub would have two downstream ports that can be used as USB3.0 and/or USB2.0.
I have assembled this already but the computers I am connecting to it seem not to recognize the USB hub at all.
From reading more online, I saw a reference to a USB MUX but I am not sure I require this. Hence why I ask here. Additionally, I am not sure if I have made any other mistake.
If we simply bridge the pairs for each orientation to the USB-C connector this would not work?
I have marked in orange the location where I believe the USB MUX  should go but I am afraid that if used it would complicate  my design more.
To clarify, I am not looking to pass display or more than 5V power to the downstream devices.


LEDs on the high-speed lines doesn't seem like a great idea.

Yup didn't know that this is not a good practice, so I will remove it. I was hoping to being able to see the "traffic" going through the chip.

Yes, it needs a MUX.
No, it will not work by bridging the pairs.
You have a 5 Gbps signal on the SS pairs. Each bit is approximately 4cm in length in the cable, and transitions between bits are a fraction of that. This signal is basically in the RF domain, or at least enough for requiring high speed design techniques.
If you simply short the pairs together, here's what happens. A signal from PC comes to your connector and gets split into two, one half travels to the hub and another half travel back to PC via the pair that the PC is currently not using. There it hits an open end which causes the signal to reflect back.
Approximately the same when the hub transmits a signal, it will get split into two, one half going to PC like it should, and one half going to PC via unused wire, where it hits an open end and reflects back to hub.
If you want it to work even as a prototype, you need to cut off the unused pairs with a knife and remove one of the CC resistors so that the cable between PC and hub will only work in the orientarion where CC pin is pulled down and the correct SS pins are connected between PC and hub.
There are also many other issues.
You can't put LEDs to HST_TX/HST_RX lines. The voltage is not enough to light them up, and even if it were, it would disturb the communicatiom, and even if it didn't, it would be constantly lit with a 5 Gbps stream even without data transmission.
You can't put a 22uF capacitor on USB VBUS. Or you can but it will violate USB specs and you won't get USB certification for it.
The USB shield connection is interesting. The specs say the shell must be connected to GND, but I don't know how good idea is to put a LC resonance circuit there.

Hello Justme,
Thank you for the details and explanation!
Yes I want initially to make the prototype work and then try to fix the issue.
So need to check what is is easier, I cut the B side cabling of the USB-C on the PCB or cut the cables inside a USB-C cable :)
The 22μF capacitor you are referring to is the C1 on the "5V to 3.3V Buck Converter" correct? The datasheet of that chip says it needs it hence why I used it.
For the USB Shield I saw some schematics like that so I copied it. But if its best to be just Grounded then easy fix.
Updated drawing

I have found this USB MUX
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/hd3ss6126.pdf
Do you think it would work if I found how to connect it in the orange section?

For the MYD-CZU3EG/4EV/5EV-V2 Development Board from MYiR which has a USB-C connector which supports  USB 3.0 the schematic shows a NXP PTN36043BXY USB Type-C SuperSpeed active switch used to multiplex the USB-C SuperSpeed signals:



Where the PTN36043BXY would be in the location of the marked in orange section of the schematic in the question, such that:

The *_AP_* nets are the SuperSpeed signals connected to the USB controller on the board.
The *_CON_1* nets connect to the SuperSpeed 1 signals on the Type-C connector.
The *_CON_2* nets connect to the SuperSpeed 2 signals on the Type-C connector.
The EXT_SEL signal selects which of the SuperSpeed 1 or 2 signals (i.e. the different orientations) are multiplexed to the USB controller on the board (the PS unit of a Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+).

The EXT_SEL is generated by a NXP PTN5150AHX USB Type-C Rev 1.1 CC-Logic which is connected to the CC1 and CC2 pins on the Type-C connector:



The PTN5150AHX also has a I2C interface to the on-board controller. The PTN5150AHX datasheet indicates it can work autonomously to control the Type-C orientation.
In response to the following part of the question:

If we simply bridge the pairs for each orientation to the USB-C connector this would not work?

While I haven't designed a USB 3.0 Type-C board myself, based upon looking at the schematics for one board, in order to work with SuperSpeed (USB 3.0) which uses differential AC-coupled signals I don't believe it is possible to design a board which can simply bridge the pairs for each orientation.
There mat be single-chip solutions which combine the USB Type-C SuperSpeed active switch and CC logic which can autonomously handle the Type-C orientation for SuperSpeed, but I haven't searched myself.

Hello Chester,
Thank you for the details!
To be honest I got lost a little bit but I will try to figure it out!
